# Laravel index and store views are in the same page approach

Tags: laravel

I have a page which views posts as well as add posts.

In my controller, I have two methods which return to the same page:

```
public function index () {
  return view('posts.index', [
    'posts' => Post::all()
  ]);
}
```

and

```
public function store (Request $request) {
  $validator = validate($request);

  if ($validator->fails()) {
    return view('posts.index', [
      'message' => $validator->messages(),
      'status' => '400'
    ]);
  } 

  $post = new Post;
  $post->title = $request->title;
  $post->body = $request->body;
  $post->user_id = 1;
  $post->save();

  return view('posts.index', [
    'message' => 'Successfully published post!',
    'status' => '200'
  ]);
}
```

Now when storing new post, the index view loses the posts data from the index method. Does it mean that in my every update, I should include posts variable?

```
public function store (Request $request) {
  $validator = validate($request);

  if ($validator->fails()) {
    return view('posts.index', [
      'message' => $validator->messages(),
      'status' => '400',
      'posts' => Post::all()
    ]);
  } 

  $post = new Post;
  $post->title = $request->title;
  $post->body = $request->body;
  $post->user_id = 1;
  $post->save();

  return view('posts.index', [
    'message' => 'Successfully published post!',
    'status' => '200',
    'posts' => Post::all()
  ]);
}
```

I am new to Laravel by the way.

Comment: After storing, don't return a view but `return redirect()->route(NAMEOFYOURINDEXROUTE)`. The `store()` method doesn't need a view (same for the `update()` method). Also: https://laravel.com/docs/master/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Comment: ahhhh okok. Thank you siiirrr! Sorry, I didn't reach that part of Laravel's documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the `store()` (and `update()` and `delete()`) methods of a Controller don't need a view. Instead of showing a view, redirect to a different route when storing/updating/deleting was successful.

Replace

```
return view('posts.index', [
    'message' => 'Successfully published post!',
    'status' => '200'
  ]);
```

with

```
return redirect()
   ->route(NAMEOFYOURINDEXROUTE)
   ->with('message', 'Successfully published post!');
```

where `NAMEOFYOURINDEXROUTE` is the name of the route you want to redirect to. (This could be a dashboard or the list/index of products etc. - you decide)

More on redirecting: https://laravel.com/docs/master/redirects
and redirecting with flash messages: https://laravel.com/docs/master/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Edit:
As @user3532758 pointed out, here's a link worth mentioning: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get (Basically, redirecting to a different route prevents accidental re-submission of the data when refreshing the page in the browser)

Comment: I think its worth mentioning the P/R/G rule.

Comment: @user3532758 Got me there, what's "_the P/R/G rule_"?

Comment: Post/Redirect/Get. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: @user3532758 Right, thanks for the link, added it to my answer